# Postgresql conditional check

Tags: postgresql

I've a users table:

```
id
type
merchant_id
agent_id
...
```

I want to add a check constraint using the following conditions:

```
if type == 'MERCHANT' then merchant_id is not null
if type == 'AGENT' then agent_id is not null
```

How this constraint is implemented?

Update:

I forgot to mention an extra requirement. the user can only have an agent_id or merchant_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the following check constraints to the create table statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER,
    type VARCHAR(55),
    merchant_id INTEGER,
    agent_id INTEGER,
    ...,
    CHECK ((type <> 'MERCHANT' OR merchant_id IS NOT NULL) AND
           (type <> 'AGENT' OR agent_id IS NOT NULL))
)
```

Comment: Super, It worked. I missed an extra req that user can have `agent_id` or `merchant_id` not both at a time so I've added extra condition:
`and ((agent_id is not null AND merchant_id is null) or (agent_id is null AND merchant_id is not null))`

Answer (score 0):

You can check constraints in CREATE TABLE command:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR (50),
    merchant_id INT (50),
    CONSTRAINT if_attribute_then_field_is_not_null 
      CHECK ( (NOT attribute) OR (field IS NOT NULL) ) 
);
```

OR in Alter Table command:

```
ALTER TABLE users 
ADD CONSTRAINT if_attribute_then_field_is_not_null 
      CHECK ( (NOT attribute) OR (field IS NOT NULL) )
);
```